# Accessing an illegal address after sbrk

Tags: page-tables

From what I understand, sbrk, unlike mmap, does not work in the granularity of a page size. For example, I could increase the heap by 100 bytes, even if it means that a page in the virtual address may be partly allocated and partly not.

My question is what stops me from accessing virtual addresses that are in the part of the page that was not allocated? The page table maps pages to frames, so if an address is in a page that was partly allocated by sbrk, what will prevent the translation from succeeding?